# How can I add dot after the subsection number?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

[image: subsectionnumbering]

I use `\usepackage{secdot}` so I achieved dot after **section** numbering. But I can't for subsection

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/secdot) is your friend.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{secdot}
\sectiondot{subsection}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: secdot]